# sql query to update all product prices

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the regular_price and sale price values ​​of all simple and variation products with a SQL query. I need to round the price when updating. to multiples of 5.
example:

```
125.35 - 125.00,
129.10 - 130.00,
128.00 - 130.00,
127.00 - 125.00
```

Comment: If you want to do this - do this. But what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE table
SET price = ROUND(price /5) * 5

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want .00 **decimal** number:

```
/* Replace 2 with your decimal count number */
UPDATE tablename SET regular_price = ROUND(ROUND(regular_price /5) * 5, 2)
```